# Load tsv file as SummarizedExperiment

Tags: r

I have received some NGS data ( sample below ) as a tsv file and shall analyze it in R.

```
# Metainfo 1                    
# Metainfo 2                    
        Sample: 8   9   10
        treatement  t1  t2  t1
probeset    symbol  feature ABC_001 ABC_002 ABC_003
1   a   11  9   118 151
2   b   12  237 770 710
3   c   13  221 966 390
4   d   14  609 723 376
```

In Bioconductor I read about '[SummarizedExperiment](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2019/BSS2019/04_Practical_CoreApproachesInBioconductor.html)' and saw that it has a similar data structure as my tsv file (sample, feature, assay). Is there a way to load my tsv file directly as SummarizedExperiment?